# How to add comment of mysql by prisma model?

Tags: prisma

`model Posts { id        Int      @id @default(autoincrement()) createdAt DateTime @default(now()) updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt title     String content   String? published Boolean  @default(false) viewCount Int      @default(0) author    User?    @relation(fields: [authorId], references: [id]) authorId  Int? }`

I am using mysql database.

I expect mysql to generate comment by prisma model.